# Get SCM information from SonarQube using WebService api

Tags: sonarqube

I want to get SCM info using WebService api with:

```
  api/sources/scm
```

But i get this response

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]}
```

SCM plugin is installed and activated.
ALL Project Permissions are grunted for Anyone.

What i am doing wrong??